# Imagemap layer on top of united states map... jquery rollovers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, photoshop, imagemap

I am trying to just make a clickable united states map in html. I think the best way is to create an imagemap with my US image and then just use jquery from there for rollovers and such. Does anyone know the best way to make imagemaps with irregular shapes (states in this case). I was looking for something in photoshop but seems like they used to have something for that but now they don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver might be you best choice: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c13a.html

Comment: it was, it stinks that is the best answer but watcha gonna do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to find an image map of the US? There are many online already made for you. For example [wikipedia commons.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg)

Here's my jQuery plugin for [doing stuff with image maps](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) with a demo using the wikipedia commons map.

I also made a simple online tool to [scale image maps](http://blog.outsharked.com/p/quick-tricks.html) which is useful if you found one for something you need to use but it's too big or too small.